Unable to locally run Typescript app due to Typescript error and regular Troubleshooting is Not Working
Normally to run an application on local server, the steps are:

Clone a branch from Gitlab
Run npm install
Run npm start

When I run these steps, I first get a warning:

WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.
You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.
SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.3.1 <4.5.0
YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 4.9.5
Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported version.

Followed by a random Typescript error. It is not always the same error.
The main issue here is that it only seems to occur to me, my colleagues are able to follow steps 1-3 and get to programming with no issue which leads me to believe there may be a program conflicting with npm, or something of the sort in my user profile and nothing wrong with the project itself.
So far I have tried everything that I have found online. I have:

moved the node and npm path to the very top in user/system env variables
moved the project to a folder separate from other projects
cleared cache and deleted node module as well as package-lock several times
uninstalled typescript and dependencies globally as well as removed duplicate dependencies
checked that npm config list matches colleagues
I have hit a dead end

These are my env variables:
    `ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
    ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.10.1
    APPDATA=C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming
    CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar;C:\Program                                               Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mq.jar
    CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
    CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
    CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
    COMPUTERNAME=ComputerName
    ComSpec=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
    DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
    HOMEDRIVE=C:
    HOMEPATH=\Users\user
    INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\include;C:\Program          Files\IBM\MQ\tools\cplus\include
    ITW_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\IcedTeaWeb\share\icedtea-web
    JAVA_HOME=C:\program files\Java\jdk21
    LIB=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\lib64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\lib
    LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local
    LOGONSERVER=\\LogonServer
    M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.2
    MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.2
    MQ_FILE_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ
    MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ
    MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java
    MQ_JRE_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\jre
    NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
    OS=Windows_NT
    Path=C:\Users\onboardingUserAppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program     Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_Apps_and_Tools_24.2.0\bin;C:\Program    Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_24.2.1\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System3  2\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\TNC Client Plugin\;C:\Program Files\PolicyPak\;C:\Program Files\PolicyPak\Cloud\;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\samples\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\samples\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\ProgramData\Gradle\gradle-6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\IcedTeaWeb\bin;C:\Users\userAppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk21\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin;C:\program files\Java\jdk21\bin;C:\program files\Java\jdk21\lib;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 140 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
    PROCESSOR_REVISION=8c01
    ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
    ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
    ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
    ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
    PROMPT=$P$G
    PSModulePath=C:\Program      Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
    PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
    SBT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\
    SESSIONNAME=Console
    SystemDrive=C:
    SystemRoot=C:\windows
    TEMP=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1
    TMP=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1
    USERDNSDOMAIN=UserDNSDomain
    USERDOMAIN=UserDomain
    USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=UserDomain
    USERNAME=user
    USERPROFILE=C:\Users\user
    windir=C:\windows
    WSLENV=WT_SESSION:WT_PROFILE_ID:`

I would like to know what other steps I can do to troubleshoot this, I have been at this for months now.
Every single thing I have tried is giving me the same result. Is there something conflicting with Typescript in my user profile?

Here are my some tips to help you.

Have you tried downgrade the typescript version?
npm install typescript@4.4.4 --save-dev
npm install @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin --save-dev
And try to run by Ctrl+Shift+P on your vscode, and restart typescript server.

Reinstall the typescript
npm list -g typescript
npm uninstall -g typescript
And try the first way again.

Downgrade your node version using nvm


Hope you any help!
